# ODBC SQL Excel Date Format

Tags: odbc

I am trying to write a query code, but the database uses a date format of "YYYYMMDD". However, the `CURRENT_DATE` function returns `YYYY-MM-DD`. `FORMAT` function doesn't work on my version. Also, I was trying to get the date of one year back.

Example:

`Today's date minus 1 year`.

I tried to use this:

`FORMAT(DATEADD(YYYY,-1,CURRENT_DATE())`.